# How to make ansible wait untill the listed items are matched?

Tags: loops, ansible, stdout

The `studout.lines` is a list of numbers, these numbers keep changing from 1 to 8, How to write a loop and ansible to wait until all the values in the list become 8

> ie { "8","8",.............? }

```
{
        "1",

        "2",

        "3",

        "1",

        "6",

        "6",

        "7",

        "7",
}
```

---

```
- name read the status file  ---
  hosts: win
  tasks:
  - name: Get
    win_shell: Get-Content C:\\temp\\status.txt
    register: value

  - name: Get-status-code
    set_fact:
      code: "{{ value.stdout_lines|list }}"

  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_items: "{{ code }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `when` ([documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement)) keyword for condition and use the jina filter `unique`. I removed also the loop as `unique` applies on the entire list.

```
- name read the status file  ---
  hosts: win
  tasks:
  - name: Get
    win_shell: Get-Content C:\\temp\\status.txt
    register: value

  - name: Get-status-code
    set_fact:
      code: "{{ value.stdout_lines|list }}"

  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ code }}"
    when: code|unique == "8"
```